# How I CONDITION all() method in laravel 5.2 (where condition)

Tags: laravel-5

[image: image of code]

```
public function createSchedule()
{
    $faculty = Faculty::all()->where('id','='1);

    $section = Section::all();
    $subject = Subject::all(['id', 'course_code', 'course_description']);
    $room = Room::all(['id', 'room_name']);
    return view('schedule.create', compact(['faculty',$faculty],['subject',$subject],['section',$section],['room',$room]));
}
```

How I CONDITION all() method in laravel 5.2 (where condition)

```
$faculty = Faculty::all()->where('id', '=', 1);
```

Comment: Your question code is `where('id', '=', 1)` but your image code is `where('id', '='1)`

Answer (score 2):

In Eloquent calling `all()` static method on model gives you collection of all the records in the table instead of query builder.

If you want to grab only one record based on it's primary key (id?) you should use `find()` method:

```
$faculty = Faculty::find(1);
```

If you want build more complex query you could use:

```
$faculty = Faculty::where('age', '>', 40)->get();
```

This will produce a collection of `Faculty` objects which meets the age condition. If you want to get only the first record that meets your requirements you could use `first()` instead of `get()`.

```
$faculty = Faculty::where('age', '>', 40)->first();
$faculty = Faculty::where('id', 1)->first();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$faculty = Faculty::where('id', '=', 1)->all();
```

Answer (score 0):

As in the answer of Chris Cynarski you can directly call `where` on the model and the `get` to get the collection that matches the condition defined in the `where` statement

```
$faculty = Faculty::where('age', '>', 40)->get();
```

But for more complex conditioning you can use the method `filter()` e.g.

`$faculty = Faculty::all()->filter(function($value, $key){
    return $value->isOld();
});`

where isOld() is a method defined in the Faculty model checking to see if the age is more than 40